# Generar big data con dompdf

Tags: php, laravel-6, dompdf

Estoy intentando generar un pdf con dompdf en laravel a partir de un html, resulta que ya aumente la memoria en el `php.ini` para que no se cuelgue debido a que el html es gigante,el problema es que `dompdf` no es capaz de convertir un documento tan grande, ¿alguien sabe una solución o una alternativa de usar una api?

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($request->view);
    return $pdf->download($audit->title . ".pdf")
```

Si el html es corto lo genera al instante

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes añadir más información? ¿Has mirado el log de Laravel a ver cual es el error que te da? ¿Puedes ponerlo aquí?

Comment: El HTML se alimenta de alguna consulta de Laravel?

Comment: No hay error,simplemente se queda cargando,no hay loops infinitos