# Dompdf se cuelga con un html muy grande en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Estoy generando pdf a partir de un html,resulta que cuando es demasiado grande DomPdf no es capaz de convertirlo,en php.init aumente la capacidad en el max_file_size y aun asi se cuelga,algun concejo?,quisiera saber si domPdf tiene algun limite?

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas, en lugar de eso intenta mejorarla https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404452/generar-big-data-con-dompdf

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Generar big data con dompdf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404452/generar-big-data-con-dompdf)